# CHITEST based on another column value in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table like this:

```
ID   Category Animal Version Value 
100     A       Dog     1      20
100     B       Cat     2      50
100     B       Dog     3      50
200     A       Dog     1      100
200     A       Cat     2      100
300     B       Cat     1      80 
400     A       Dog     1      80
```

I need to calculate CHITEST on column `value` based on `category`. The built-in CHITEST example in Excel only supports two separate row.

How can I use column Category to calculate CHITEST for column value?

Answer (score 0):

Chitest works on more than two rows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mike. But instead of actual/expected value, i want to use category A and category B.